# Delete file only if it's bigger than 10 GB

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if a specific file called `my_file_name.txt` in directory `~/Library/myfiledir` is over 10 GB, and if it is, I want to delete it. I will run this command as a cronjob every hour.

This is what I have, but it's a guess and I don't really want to run it if I'm wrong:

```
find ~/Library/myfiledir -size +10G -name "my_file_name.txt" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Is this correct? Am I missing any forward slashes, etc?

Comment: You could always test it (using a different file in a different directory if you're worried about mucking something up)

Comment: what's the point of using find here, you know the path already; just use stat and an if

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ can it be a one liner? I don't know, that's why I asked

Comment: `~` expands to the home directory of the current user, you want to make sure that you end up in the correct directory.

Comment: `if [ $(stat -c %s file) -gt 1000000000 ] ; then rm file ; fi`

Comment: If you do use `find`, prefer `-delete` over `-exec rm '{}' \;`. (Note that you have to escape / quote the `{}`.) It is safer and faster.

Comment: @5gon12eder I've never needed to quote `{}`. Why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: Are you really going to use the `-i` option in a cronjob? How will you answer the question?

Comment: @Barmar Because it has special meaning to the shell. However, I have just tried without quoting and it seems that the shell only interprets it contextually and indeed leaves it alone in command arguments. I didn't know that. The man page of `find` quotes it and I have always blindly followed that advise. (I don't know any other program than `find` that I would pass `{}` as argument.) So I guess that part of my precious comment was wrong. (Of course, quoting it doesn't do any harm either, so you might as well do it anyway.)

Comment: `{}` only has special meaning if there's something inside it. `{1..3}` expands to `1 2 3`, `foo{a,b,c}` expands to `fooa foob fooc`. But `{}` by itself has no special meaning and is left alone.

Comment: Interestingly, `echo { date }` also “works” and prints `{ date }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command should work, but it can be simplified:

```
find ~/Library/myfiledir/my_file_name.txt -size +10G -exec rm -i {} \;
```

This way it doesn't search the entire directory when you're just interested in a single file.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why choose this over the `-delete` arg?

Comment: Old habits, not dependent on a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
find ~/Library/myfiledir/my_file_name.txt -size +10G -delete
```

with GNU's -delete switch, which is easier to read and write.

Comment: Not only easier, also safer as it is immune to file system races. It will also be faster since you don't have to spawn a child process. (When dealing with a 10 GB file, this arguably doesn't matter that much, though.)